# How do I find the image URL to, in order to place a background image?

Tags: css, image

I've found instruction on where to place this image

```css
body { background-image: url(example1.jpg); }
```

But I can;t figure out how to format or get the `"url"( )` it's looking for. Do I need to save it in a different place, or format my image differently?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this CSS:

```
body {
    background: transparent url(http://mydomain/content/image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

or of course:

```
body {
    background-image:   url(content/content/image.jpg);
}
```

Your URL can be **absolute**, like in the first example – or **relative**, like in the second. You have to notice, that when placing a relative path, it is relative to your stylesheet definition, not your HTML-Document. Example with directories:

```
- webroot
    index.html
    img/image.jpg
    css/main.css
```

When you put the definition from above into the **index.html** the URL would be:

```
url(img/image.jpg)
```

but when you place it inside the **main.css** it would be

```
url(../img/image/jpg)
```

One final thought on this: If you have **blanks/whitespaces** in your path, you have to wrap the url in single or double quotes like:

```
url('image/my image.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any standard url such as
http://example.com/xx.jpg
 or from your directory
/images/xx.jpg
Is this what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You put the url in relative to the stylesheet, NOT the site root. For instance if you have this structure:

```
root
- images/
  - image.gif
- css/
   - styles.css
- index.html
```

The your url path would be `url('../images/image.gif');`

On an unrelated note (and just because I found this out the other day), if you're using a .htc file (like PIE.htc for IE rounded corners for example) then the behavior url needs to be relative to the root and not the stylesheet.

Comment: Or simply `/images/image.gif`.